# How to hide/show the select tags using a select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my code has a 1 parent select tag with a 2 options apples and butter each options has a value of 1 and 2 when I select the apple it will show another select tag and vise versa, and my problem is it will show another select and another, I need to hide the another select and show the another select, can you help me?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#defList').on('change', function() {
    var tarSelect = $(this).val();
    console.log(tarSelect);
    if (tarSelect == 1) {
      var arrayList = [{
        val: 1,
        text: 'one'
      }, {
        val: 2,
        text: 'two'
      }, {
        val: 3,
        text: 'three'
      }];

      var selectList = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox');
      $(arrayList).each(function() {
        selectList.append($('<option>').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
      });

    } else if (tarSelect == 2) {
      var arrayList2 = [{
        val: 1,
        text: 'one'
      }, {
        val: 2,
        text: 'two'
      }, {
        val: 3,
        text: 'three'
      }];


      var selectList2 = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox').remove();
      $(arrayList2).each(function() {
        selectList2.append($('<option>').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
      });

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="defList">
  <option value="1">Apples</option>
  <option value="2">Butter</option>
</select>

<div id="selectBox">
</div>
```

Comment: `my problem is it will show another select and another, I need to hide the another select and show the another select` which another?

Comment: It will be created a new select list which declared on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the #selectBox content when the first drowpdown value is changed

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  
       function createDropdown(arrayList){
         
           var $select = $('<select>');
   $(arrayList).each(function () {
   $select.append($('<option>').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));  
   });
         return $select;
         }
  
  $('#defList').on('change', function(){
          $("#selectBox").empty();
   var tarSelect = $(this).val();
   console.log(tarSelect);
   if(tarSelect == 1) {  
   var arrayList = 
   [
   {val: 1,text: 'one'},
   {val: 2,text: 'two'},
   {val: 3,text: 'three'}
   ];
          createDropdown(arrayList).appendTo('#selectBox');
  
  } else if (tarSelect == 2) {
   var arrayList2 = 
   [
   {val: 1,text: 'one'},
   {val: 2,text: 'two'},
   {val: 3,text: 'three'}
   ];
   
   createDropdown(arrayList2).appendTo('#selectBox');  
   
  }
  
  }); 
  $('#defList').trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <P>Hello world!</p>
  
  <select id="defList">
   <option value="1">Apples</option>
   <option value="2">Butter</option>
  </select>
 

  <div id="selectBox">
 
  
  </div>
 
  
   
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Yes it works but it is possible to show the default select tag?

Comment: yes , you have to trigger a change Event (I've updated the snippet)

Comment: It worked so the trigger() will be initiated on load of the document?

Comment: Why all the code duplication? This can easily be cleaned up

Answer (score 1):

You can just clear the new select area initially using `$('#selectBox').html("");`

But also change `var selectList2 = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox').remove();` to `var selectList2 = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#defList').on('change', function() {
         $('#selectBox').html("");
   var tarSelect = $(this).val();
   console.log(tarSelect);
   if (tarSelect == 1) {
    var arrayList = [{
      val: 1,
      text: 'A one'
     },
     {
      val: 2,
      text: 'A two'
     },
     {
      val: 3,
      text: 'A three'
     }
    ];
              
            
    var selectList = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox');
    $(arrayList).each(function() {
     selectList.append($('<option>').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    });

   } else if (tarSelect == 2) {
    var arrayList2 = [{
      val: 1,
      text: 'B one'
     },
     {
      val: 2,
      text: 'B two'
     },
     {
      val: 3,
      text: 'B three'
     }
    ];


    var selectList2 = $('<select>').appendTo('#selectBox');
    $(arrayList2).each(function() {
     selectList2.append($('<option>').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    });

   }

  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
 <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
 <P>Hello world!</p>

 <select id="defList">
  <option value="1">Apples</option>
  <option value="2">Butter</option>
 </select>

 <div id="selectBox">

 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: is it possible that when you select the apples it will show the select tag?